# JSON tag to decode into a struct in Golang

Tags: json, go, struct

I have a JSON like this:

```
{
"add":[{"id": "1234ABCD"}, {"id": "5678EFGH"}]
}
```

And I have a struct like this:

```
type ExampleStruct struct {
    Added   []string
}
```

I am wondering what JSON tag I should put in my struct so that after I do the JSON decoding (code not shown here) and then call `exampleStruct := &ExampleStruct` followed by `exampleStruct.Added`, how can I get `["1234ABCD", "5678EFGH"]`?

I tried doing this:

```
type ExampleStruct struct {
    Added   []string `json:"add"`
}
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: What the point if an array of `id` if you're using only first item?
Why no add a method to `ExampleStruct` and fetch first item.

Comment: There's a possibility that there's more than one `id` that could be added from the API call. I just added one for brevity.

Comment: __more than one id that could be added__ and then if you call  `ExampleStruct.Added` you still get the first item?

Comment: I have edited my question a little bit. If you see now, when I call `ExampleStruct.Added`, I should get a slice of strings in this format: `["1234ABCD", "5678EFGH"]`

Comment: But `Added` is not a function, you cannot call it.

Comment: In my answer I have added a function `Added` that returns `["1234ABCD", "5678EFGH"]` from your example data. Hope this helps.

Comment: you can use this https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/ just copy your JSON and it'll tell you the Go struct

Answer (score 1):

Use a slice of maps instead of strings, as you have key-value pairs of strings.

```
    type ExampleStruct struct {
        Added []map[string]string `json:"add"`
    }
```

Here is a full example:

```
    package main

    import (
        "bytes"
        "encoding/json"
        "fmt"
    )

    func main() {
        const code = `{
    "add":[{"id": "1234ABCD"}]
    }`
        type ExampleStruct struct {
            Added []map[string]string `json:"add"`
        }
        var data ExampleStruct
        json.NewDecoder(bytes.NewReader([]byte(code))).Decode(&data)
        fmt.Println(data)
    }
```

**EDIT**

Since you want to have only the values of the maps, here is a complete example where `Added` is a function that can be called on the `ExampleStruct`. It assumes that each map only contains two strings (id and value):

```
    package main

    import (
        "bytes"
        "encoding/json"
        "fmt"
    )

    func main() {
        const code = `{
    "add":[{"id": "1234ABCD"}, {"id": "5678EFGH"}]
    }`
        var data ExampleStruct
        json.NewDecoder(bytes.NewReader([]byte(code))).Decode(&data)
        fmt.Println(data)
        fmt.Println(data.Added())
    }

    type ExampleStruct struct {
        Add []map[string]string `json:"add"`
    }

    func (e ExampleStruct) Added() []string {
        values := make([]string, len(e.Add))
        for i := range e.Add {
            for _, v := range e.Add[i] {
                values[i] = v
            }
        }
        return values
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to obtain its key by adding 'id', like this

type ExampleStruct struct {
    Added   []string `json:"add.id"`
}

Comment: No I tried that but it doesn't work because `id` is contained in the object which is contained in an array, and the array is the value of the `add` key of the JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to arrange your `json` such a way that elements of the struct should be accessible directly (without over-engineering it).

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type ExampleStruct struct {
    Add []struct {
        ID string `json:"id"`
    } `json:"add"`
}

func main() {

    const code = `{
     "add":[{"id": "1234ABCD"}, {"id": "5678EFGH"}]
    }`

     var data ExampleStruct
     json.NewDecoder(bytes.NewReader([]byte(code))).Decode(&data)
     fmt.Println(data)           //Get all ids: {[{1234ABCD} {5678EFGH}]}
     fmt.Println(data.Add[0].ID) //Get 1st ID : 1234ABCD
     fmt.Println(data.Add[1].ID) //Get 2nd ID ... and so on.: 5678EFGH
}
```

You can find the code here https://play.golang.org/p/7tD4fLBewp .

If you have many `ids` in an array then you can also write a function to loop over the array i.e `data.Add`and get ids from that.